# Mount virtual disk device and access to it without being root

Tags: permissions, qemu, block-device, nbd

I am trying to create a virtual disk to share data with a VirtualBox VM not connected to the Internet.
I proceed like follows

```
qemu-img create -f qcow2 hdd.img 2G
sudo modprobe nbd max_part=16
sudo qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 hdd.img
sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/nbd0 
sudo mount /dev/nbd0 /mnt
sudo mkdir /mnt/foo
```

I would now get rid of root permissions, but:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /mnt/foo
```

does not seem to work.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/118199/693277

Answer (score 0):

Given the feedback by @Kamil Maciorowski, I tried the following approach:

```
qemu-img create -f qcow2 hdd.img 2G
sudo qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 hdd.img
sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/nbd0 
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/vhd
sudo mount /dev/nbd0 /mnt/vhd -o dmask=000,fmask=000
```

Now I can use the virtual disk without sudoing for each write operation, as the permissions for `/mnt/vhd` are:

```
drwxrwxrwx
```

However, there are still two weird things. After mounting,  `/mnt/vhd` is owned by `root:root` and I can't change the owner with `sudo chown ...`. Also, the date of `/mnt/vhd` is set to Jan 01 1970.